# How to parse item from list in python

Tags: python, parsing, arraylist

How do I parse an item from the list in python?

I need to get a HOSTNAME from:
`{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'HOSTNAME'}`

```
tag = [{'Key': 'Backup Initiator Rule', 'Value': 'Daily-6d-retention'}, 
        {'Key': 'delete_On', 'Value': '2019-08-31'},
        {'Key': 'Backup_Type', 'Value': 'Demo'},
        {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'HOSTNAME'},
        {'Key': 'Disaster_Recovery', 'Value': 'Full'}]
```

Comment: get `tag["Tags"]` then scan the list for a dictionary where Key == Name. Use `ast.literal_eval` on it first since it seems to be a string

Comment: this appears to be a python dictionary written to string. why? can you change that?

Comment: but this string contains a "datetime.datetime" call... `'StartTime': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 28, 13, 56, 8, 269000, tzinfo=tzutc()),`

Comment: i expect that that's not a call that's a datetime object's string representation

Comment: type of variable tag is the class 'list'

Comment: `tag = [{'Key': 'Backup Initiator Rule', 'Value': 'Daily-6d-retention'}, {'Key': 'delete_On', 'Value': '2019-08-31'},{'Key': 'Backup_Type', 'Value': 'Demo'},{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'HOSTNFFFAME'},{'Key': 'Disaster_Recovery', 'Value': 'Full'}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try List Comp**:

```
tag = "[{'Key': 'Backup Initiator Rule', 'Value': 'Daily-6d-retention'}, {'Key': 'delete_On', 'Value': '2019-08-31'},{'Key': 'Backup_Type', 'Value': 'Demo'},{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'HOSTNAME'},{'Key': 'Disaster_Recovery', 'Value': 'Full'}]"

print([dic['Value'] for dic in eval(tag) if dic['Key']=='Name'])
```

**Results**: ['HOSTNAME']

Comment: how to be in case if the type of variable 'tag' is `class 'list'`

Comment: `tag = [{'Key': 'Backup Initiator Rule', 'Value': 'Daily-6d-retention'}, {'Key': 'delete_On', 'Value': '2019-08-31'},{'Key': 'Backup_Type', 'Value': 'Demo'},{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'HOSTNAME'},{'Key': 'Disaster_Recovery', 'Value': 'Full'}]`

Comment: Just change "eval(tag)"  to tag.

Answer (score 1):

**Regex**

Since this is not parseable json i would go for the regex way:

```
import re
re.findall("{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': '(.*?)'}", tag)
```

This returns a list of all objects found:

```
['HOSTNAME']
```

**Edit** OP changed the *tag* string, this might not be the best option now.

Answer (score 0):

```
for dict in tag:
    if dict['Key'] == 'Name':
        hostname = dict['Value']
        break
```

Comment: I meant list `<class 'list'>`